# Format decimal inside of json object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am using a webservice to get JSON from to fill up a Chartjs chart. When I pull from the webservice it is JSON, and Chartjs takes objects a in a specific format like this:

```
      $scope.data.push({
        'value': x.score,
        'color': '#424242',
        'highlight': '#686868',
        'label': x.name
      });
```

The `x.score` is pulled directly from the JSON object from the ajax call and is just placed right inside the other array of objects. Previously before using charts I was just using a table, so in the html I used `x.score.toFixed(3)` to trim it down, which is what i want to do now. Although, when I try to just add `toFixed(3)` to the end of `x.score` while it is like this, the site crashes. It is still javascript is it not? Then why can I not dot that? What are my alternatives to get 3 decimal places after?

This is how I have it in the page where I am using the same value in a table:

```
<td>{{item.score.toFixed(3)}}</td>
```

This trims it fine. What is the difference?

**EDIT [some more info]**

So here is a bigger chunk:

```
returnedData.models.forEach(function(x) {
        var score = x.score.toFixed(3);
        console.debug(score);
        if (score >= 75) {
          $scope.data.push({
            'value': score,
            'color': '#F7464A',
            'highlight': '#FF5A5E',
            'label': x.name
          });
        } else if (score >= 50) {
          $scope.data.push({
            'value': score,
            'color': '#FDB45C',
            'highlight': '#FFC870',
            'label': x.name
          });
        } else {
          $scope.data.push({
            'value': score,
            'color': '#424242',
            'highlight': '#686868',
            'label': x.name
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

I get the `console.debug` value for every entry, but the second I want to either say `'value':score,` or `'value':x.score.toFixed(3)` the chart doesnt load?

Here is picture of incident:

[image]

Comment: Is x.score a number string or just a number?

Comment: What does "the site crashes" mean?

Comment: The chart does not load. There are no errors though in the Javascript console. So I am not sure what the issue would be

Comment: @erp could you paste those error in your question

Comment: Wrap that statement in a try/catch, and log any exception.

Comment: What would that tell me, I know where the error is occuring, and there are no errors showing up in the console.

Comment: Try putting adding a console.log(item.score.toFixed(3)) to your code and see if it actually outputs the value you are expecting.  My guess is that you are running into an issue where item.score is either empty or contains a string. I'm not sure why you wouldn't be getting an error, though.

Comment: updated op some more details

Comment: Does `chartJS` expect that to be a non-decimal number or a string?

Comment: And it works fine without the `toFixed`?

Comment: Yes, which is the weird part/why I am here :p